# Accessing (non public) Google Sites pages with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, google-sites

i am trying to read the content of a non-public Google Site Page. I wrote the php Script for reading a public Google Sites Page, so it is using php's file_get_content().

Is there a way to login the php script so it is able to access the non public Google Sites Page?

Comment: You can use cURL to post your login credentials and then get the page you need from the cURL result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some old code that does something similar. Should get you started

```
/* Prepare cURL */
$ch = curl_init();  

// set these according to the login form
$login_query = http_build_query(
                    array('username'=> 'username',
                        'password' => 'your_password',
                        'login' => 'log in'));

/* Set options */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.yourpage.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'www.yourpage.com'); //set this to whatever the normal login does
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); //set to something resonable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookie.txt'); // make sure directory is writable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$urlcontent = utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

// at this point you are logged in... get your page

/* Initiate cURL request */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.yourpage.com/what-you-want');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'www.yourpage.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/* Send cURL request */
$result_data = utf8_encode(curl_exec($ch));
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);

/* Close cURL */
curl_close($ch);

/* Handle result if any */
if ($this->curl_info['http_code'] == 200)
{
    // at this point your page is in $result_data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a page that requires some sort of posts, sessions or anything, i'd suggest you to use `CURL` instead of file_get_contents. You can read more about it on [the documentation](http://dk.php.net/curl).

If it will work for googles non-public pages, im unsure of. It can turn into a great challenge though :-)